# Using an enum and a payload map to get an implicit second argument of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm currently writing a function that takes two arguments.
The first being the key of an enum, and the second depends on the first argument.

Some of the keys don't require a second argument, so when I assign undefined in the payload map, the function explicity requires to pass in undefined.

Is there a way I can pass in the first key, and not pass in a second argument, while fulfilling the type requirements?

Code:

```js
export enum MyKey {
  BleepBloop = 'BleepBloop',
  BeepBoop = 'BeepBoop',
  BingBong = 'BingBong',
}

export type SubstitutionsMap = {
  [MyKey.BleepBloop]: [string, string];
  [MyKey.BeepBoop]: [string, string];
  [MyKey.BingBong]: undefined;
};

export const getFoo = <K extends MyKey>(key: K, substitutions: SubstitutionsMap[K]): string => {
    // Handle private logic
    return ''
};

getFoo(MyKey.BingBong) // <--- Error is here
```

Error:

```
(enum member) MyKey.BingBong = "BingBong"
Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)
index.ts(13, 49): An argument for 'substitutions' was not provided.
```

This error is gone when I explicitly pass in undefined, but I would like to not have to pass in a second argument if it's just undefined.

This fixes my error:

```js
getFoo(MyKey.BingBong, undefined)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create function overloads for `getFoo` that matches your required types.

Something like below:

```
function getFoo(key: MyKey.BingBong): string;
function getFoo<K extends MyKey.BeepBoop | MyKey.BleepBloop>(
  key: K,
  substitutions: SubstitutionsMap[K]
): string;
function getFoo(key: MyKey, substitutions?: SubstitutionsMap): string {
  if (key === MyKey.BingBong) {
    // code in which I don't need substitutions
  }

  if (substitutions) {
    // code in which I do need to access substitutions
  }

  return '';
}

getFoo(MyKey.BleepBloop);                 //error!
getFoo(MyKey.BleepBloop, ['asd', 'qwe']); //fine
getFoo(MyKey.BeepBoop);                   //error!
getFoo(MyKey.BeepBoop, ['asd', 'qwe']);   //fine
getFoo(MyKey.BingBong);                   //fine
getFoo(MyKey.BingBong, ['asd', 'qwe']);   //error!
```

This will make it so that when  the first argument is `MyKey.BingBong`, it will not let you pass a second argument, but if it is another member of `MyKey`, it will require you to pass a second argument.

Comment: Then I lose the required second argument of the other two keys

Comment: @UzairAshraf updated my answer to get the behaviour I think you want

Comment: I plan on having over 100 keys in my actual code, seems like this would be come huge very quickly...

Comment: I was able to solve it with your help, thank you!